# What does it mean that this close vote review is "invalidated"?

Tags: support, flagging, review-queue

I had recently flagged [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/identify-soundtrack-used-by-jincheng-zhang) asking to identify a soundtrack used by Jincheng Zhang for closure because the linked video has been deleted and this makes the question obsolete. This is the only post by the OP, who has not returned to the site since receiving an answer from @Bebs. In particular, they have not responded to the comments mentioning that the link to the video is dead, and it appears unlikely that they will do so.

My flag was marked as helpful but the post had not been closed, so I checked the [timeline](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/posts/7602/timeline) of the post and saw that the close review has been marked as "invalidated".

Can someone explain to me what it means for it to be "invalidated"? In the [review queue](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/close/7453), I see that there is one event, namely that @Bebs marked the question for closure on April 1. Then, the close review was closed on April 6 as "invalidated". Does this mean that no one else reviewed this item so it expired from the queue?

---

After posting this question, I went through all my off-topic flags that were marked helpful with the question remaining open. By checking the timelines, I usually found the close vote to be "invalidated" or I did not find an entry for the review queue in the timeline at all:

- [0 reviews](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/close/7467)
- <s>[2 close votes](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/close/7455)</s>
- <s>[1 close vote](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/close/7248)</s>

(Update: some of the questions are deleted so I have struck out their links.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The review aged away. See [What does 'close invalidated' mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279553/what-does-close-invalidated-mean) for more info.

In general we could use more participation in the queues. I don't mind cleaning them out every few weeks, but mod votes are binding and getting feedback from the community on these topics is vital.