# Can this ID question be closed for lacking details -? "Persian song: can you please tell me what this song is called?"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question

The song ID question [Persian song: can you please tell me what this song is called?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6757/3955) was asked around two years ago and self-answered (and accepted) around a year ago.

The question only contains a link to a clip of a song on Google Drive, and the title says it's a Persian song. The answer says the song name is "Avase Negah", but does not provide a link.

The lack of details in the question as well as the answer make me feel that the post is better off closed. I tried improving the answer by providing a link to the song, but Googling the song title brings up no hits, except the SE question itself.

I voted to close the question on Feb 12, but the close vote review was [invalidated](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/496/3955) on Feb 20 (this can be checked in the [timeline](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/posts/6757/timeline) of the question). If it were completed and left open, then I might not have made a Meta post about it, but since it was invalidated I felt it would be good to bring attention to it.

So, in conclusion, I request that the ID question under discussion be closed for lacking details.

Answer (score 3):

The votes aged away. Nothing was rejected by the community, we just didn't act in time.

I personally think this is an extremely low quality question and I have down voted this, but I don't know if we should close it. Our current policy on these questions is too lax on things like this. Not enough detail implies that we can't reasonably answer it as is, but it has an answer. Neither the question or answer is high quality, but that's another matter that I think is also important but a much different discussion.

We have two paths here:

- Let voting be the quality control and let this question remain open, just downvote and move on.
- Create a quality control to close these questions and not allow answers until a minimum quality is met.

The former is something we can do right away, while the latter is something I'd love for us to have, but we need the community as a whole to buy in and strongly enforce.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that that this question should be closed, and I voted for closure.

It is true that there is no details, no google-potential for someone asking a similar question (that's why I downvoted it), and the answer itself should be closed for low quality (I downvoted it too).

However, since the community decided it was a good Q&A, there is nothing much we can do... don't forget you still have the downvote as mean of expression.

Comment: I don't think that community consensus was arrived at, because the close vote review was invalidated with [2 VTC and 1 LO](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/close/10089). If the review were completed rather than invalidated, then I would agree that there is little point in bringing up a Meta question about it.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who knows the song that's enough detail.
For someone who doesn't know the song no amount of information is going to help them give an answer.

Comment: While I don’t necessarily disagree with the content of this answer as it stands, it seems to be addressing an exteme position that I am not advocating for, namely that any question that I _personally_ cannot answer should be closed because it lacks enough details for _me_ to answer it.